# При запуске консоли\дизайна javafx\консоли в эклипсе работа с файлами прекращается

Tags: java, файлы, javafx, cmd, файловая-система

есть jar/exe файл, который копирует сам себя и удаляет, при запуске с консоли windows, он перестает это все делать, как и при запуске приложения с дизайном javafx, происходит то же самое, почему такое может быть? И как мне обойти эту ловушку?
И да, если копировать любой другой файл, то все работает.Когда его запускаешь без дизайна\консоли, то он все делает
Код:

```
FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(new File(jarLocate)).getChannel();
    FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\"+jarName)).getChannel();
  try {
    source.transferTo(0, source.size(), dest);
  } finally {
    source.close();
    dest.close();
  }
```

```
   File file = new File(rd);
           if (file.delete()) {
               System.out.println(" Файл "+rd+" успешно удалён!");
           } else {
               System.out.println(" Файл "+rd+" не существует.");
           }
```

Comment: Этот файл исполняется и сейчас занят процессом. Как его можно скопировать?

Comment: так прикол в том, что когда я его запускаю без консоли и дизайна, то все копируется и удаляется

Comment: ок, может быть дизайн мешает, но и это я решил проверить, я закрывал дизайн(программно 'stage.close();') но все равно файл не удалялся